# Finding domain of holomorphicity of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Given that $f(z)=|x^2-y^2|+2i|xy|$ for all $z=x+iy\in \mathbb C$. We have to find the domain of holomorphicity of $f$. But question is how to find partial derivatives of real and imaginary parts of $f$ to check for Cauchy Riemann equation?

Comment: Look at $z^2$ on octants.

Comment: Please elaborate a bit@ Dr. MV

Comment: I've posted a HINT which gives a bit more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Note that $z^2=(x^2-y^2)+i(2xy)$.  Then, analyze cases.  For example, one case is the set for which $x>0$, $y>0$, and $x>y$.